# Vue2: Downloaded PDF Is Corrupt

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

A button should download a PDF that is generated on the fly. The PDF is generated correctly by the API, **the file processed by the client-side code is corrupt and will not open**.

**Process Flow:**

1. Button is clicked
2. `exportDataAsPDFAction` is triggered
3. `POST` request is constructed and executed
4. Response contains raw PDF file
5. File download is started by following callback logic:

---

```
this.exportDataAsPDFAction({
  gridKey: this.grid.Key,
  callback: response => {
    let hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

    // This seems to be the problem area
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + window.btoa(encodeURIComponent(response));
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'Results.pdf';
    hiddenElement.click();
  }
});
```

---

**Extra:**

Performing the same task with CSV as the desired format works. The only difference there is that encoding and filename extension:

```
hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURI(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `hiddenElement.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);`

Comment: TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL'